# Missing account information for Google OAuth - NextAuth.js

Tags: oauth, next-auth

Here's my NextAuth config -

```
export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise, { databaseName: "letterspace" }) as Adapter,
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: getGoogleCredentials().clientId,
      clientSecret: getGoogleCredentials().clientSecret,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          prompt: "consent",
          access_type: "offline",
          response_type: "code",
          scope: "openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token }: any) {
      if (token) {
        session.user.id = token.id;
        session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      }
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, account, user, profile }) {
      console.log("# JWT CALLBACK #")
      console.log({token, account, user, profile})
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

I sign-in using `signIn('google)` and try to access account information by using `getToken({ req })`.

On first sign-in, this is what I see from my logs (refer jwt callback method) -

```
# JWT CALLBACK #
{
  token: {
    sub: '64bfa95e89f53a5b82a3b15c',
    accessToken: 'ya29.a0AbVbY6PTi58GHvgFnHCBHuNoOUvsJxD_U46MFrynAYW6FauLVD7Hk0kA3A5GcRWAH65K6y8v41QN82ssRjZGuQ6Ul_npXoGqNnKjKCcec_3dMufoynD16Ben_3D9RZf9QZ7Ys6-CcjdXqbmHzyD9Cx2KJ8WNaCgYKAVwSARISFQFWKvPldFA9qxISGh8rZyBdrzaDNQ0163',
    iat: 1690282334,
    exp: 1692874334,
    jti: '1c3e5941-61d6-4089-87a5-09119ac17778'
  },
  account: undefined,
  user: undefined,
  profile: undefined
}
```

Ideally, I was expecting account name, email and picture to be coming along with token. But all I see is undefined.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Hi, Does this answer your question [GAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76767770/14886384)

Comment: @TirathSharma No, that doesn't help.

Comment: Did you checked code by opening link mentioned in third point. As I am getting all like fullname, email, picture, is_email_verified and more information by same code.